# Swift Parse - Create new record in two classes

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am registering a new user and due to that, I am creating a new record for this user in _User class provided by Parse. I have another custom class in Parse that I would like to update in the same query or request. Is this possible?

Here is what I have for creating the user row in User class.

```
let user = PFUser()
            user.username = userObject.email
            user.email = userObject.email
            user.password = userObject.password
            user["mobile"] = userObject.mobile
            user["name"] = userObject.name
             user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let error = error {
                   print(“Error Occurred”)
                }else{
                    //Successful
                   print(“Successful Record Creation”)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. In the `else` part of your code once you know the user was created successfully, you can just create a new `PFObject` of whatever class name you want, give it appropriate values, and then save it in the background.

Comment: Yup that's what I tried and it worked. Nonetheless, thanks for answering as it will help someone else who comes across looking for a similar solution.